# How to efficiently split pcap files based on TCP stream?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I am trying to split large pcap files containing hundreds of TCP streams into separate files. My current approach (see below) seems quite inefficient to me. My question is: *What is the most efficient way of splitting pcap files into separate files by TCP stream?*

#### Current approach

In my current approach, I first use tshark to find out which TCP streams are in the file. Next, for each of these TCP streams, I read the original file and extract the given stream. The code snippet below shows my approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get all TCP stream numbers
for stream in `tshark -r $file -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -n | uniq`
do
    # Extract specified stream from $file and write it to a separate file.
    tshark -r "$file" -Y "tcp.stream eq $stream" -w "$file.$stream.pcap"
done
```

However, this approach seems inefficient as tshark has to read the pcap file several times (once for each stream). I would ideally like a solution that goes over the original pcap file once and upon finding a packet belonging to a specific connection, append it to that file.

#### Other approaches

I have looked around for other approaches as well, but they do not seem to suit my situation:

- [PcapPlusPlus' PcapSplitter](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/PcapSplitter) has a slightly different definition of a TCP connection. They define 'connection' as the same (protocol, source ip, destination ip, source port, destination port)-tuple, which might show weird behaviour if multiple TCP streams have the same tuple. I believe wireshark/tshark actually base their TCP streams on the SYN:SYN-ACK and FIN:FIN-ACK flags (but please correct me if I am wrong).
- [Python's Scapy](https://scapy.net/) Scapy has the same problem as PcapSplitter in that it does not provide any way of splitting TCP streams apart from the 5-tuple described above. (Of course I could write this myself, but that would be beyond the scope of my current work).

Also for both of these solutions, I am not entirely sure whether they are able to correctly handle erroneous captures.

#### Question

Therefore, I would like to have some suggestions on how to split pcap files into separate files based on TCP stream in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Tracewrangler](https://www.tracewrangler.com/)?  It's for Windows but the [documentation](https://www.tracewrangler.com/download/doc/tracewrangler.pdf) does mention that it can run under [wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

That's probably the best tool I can think of, but you might want to have a look at some others listed on the Wireshark wiki [Tools](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) page.

Comment: Hmm I’m not sure softwares ran on Wine will make a software run faster than using tshark directly :/ Wine isn’t really known for its performance...

Comment: Well, Tracewrangler seems to run very well natively on Windows, so if you have a Windows PC available, you could try it there.  If not, you could always try it under wine and benchmark it against your current strategy to compare the performance.  Anyway, the tool is free and quite handy for those of us who can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way (in performance point of view) is obliviously a dedicated program for the task.

[libpcap-library](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap) may have needed functions for implementing such:

- `pcap_open_offline` for opening a pcap file for reading
- `pcap_dump_open` for opening pcap files for writing
- `pcap_dump` for write packet to target files
- And bunch of functions for filtering/handling the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pkt2flow:
https://github.com/caesar0301/pkt2flow

````
Usage: ./pkt2flow [-huvx] [-o outdir] pcapfile

    Options:
        -h  print this help and exit
        -u  also dump (U)DP flows
        -v  also dump the in(v)alid TCP flows without the SYN option
        -x  also dump non-UDP/non-TCP IP flows
        -o  (o)utput directory```
````